# Disable file_get_contents to protect html contents

Tags: php, curl, cross-domain

I want to disable `file_get_contents` function to protect html contents from a web page.

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.net/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

I already did the `allow_url_fopen = Off` and it is not working.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can research User-Agent filtering, which is a common (and expectedly unreliable) *workaround*. Also, to be somewhat blunt, nothing in your blog is actually worth copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done through page header. Following is the script.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
?>
```

Place this script before any out put starts.

- First checking for user agent header and `file_get_contents` not sending user agent
- Most browsers and search engines will send the user agent
- If `HTTP_USER_AGENT` not set send the page not found message

It can be tested at following url: http://sugunan.net/demo/content.php

Comment: You're kidding, right? I've pretty much **never** seen a bot that doesn't send a User Agent string that is specifically designed to make it look like a regular browser.

Comment: I just want to disable the `file_get_contents` function to get contents via http links

Comment: this really wont achieve anything, it may well block legitimate users of the site.

Comment: @Dagon Whatever I found this way very effective and My problem is solved.

Comment: @Bira Seriously; I identify hundreds of bots a month. *Not a single one* uses a blank user agent. Ever. In fact; the fact that you say this answer 'works' for you makes this entire question/answer look... off...